# Как написать обычный djvu reader на android?

Tags: android

Нужно написать обычную djvu читалку, в интернете почти нет информации, если у кого то был такой опыт, подскажите куда копать.

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий. Он не предполагает объективно верного ответа. Возможно имеет место, разбить вопрос на несколько задач, типа "Компонент под android для просмотра контента в формате djvu". Если же на тот вопрос ответ не найдется - придется задавать вопросы по спецификации самого формата djvu. парсить и отрисовывать...

Comment: Простой путь: ищете написанную библиотеку для работы с DJVU и используете ее или отдельно взятые фрагменты исходного кода, предварительно изучив, найти можно на sourceforge к примеру. Очень тяжелый путь: ищете спецификацию DJVU, долго и нудно вчитываетесь и пытаетесь реализовать все, что там написано. Рекомендую простой - найти готовую библиотеку.